# Wordpress Permalinks 404 bug with "next" button

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I have changed wordpress to use permalinks for post names. `/%postname%/` so that they are in the form `wordpress.com/sample-post`.
The permalinks work great but it messes up the "next" and "previous" buttons. The default permalink structure works great, but whenever I change the permalinks to any other form, the next button link gets changed to `wordpress.com/page/2`. which doesn't exist... how do I get the buttons to link to the correct place?

It appears this is a bug on wordpresses side, but I can't find any answers to this problem directly.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite really enabled?

Comment: @toscho Where do I look to find out?

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines from your .htaccess. If your site breaks, mod_rewrite is off. :)

Comment: @toscho it appears to be on. Nothing broke when I removed the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by editing my `.htaccess` file. I replaced it with the following.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping this site and your question constructive by posting your own solution. +1